# How to create a gradually increasing PIN in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a project where I'm generating a random PIN. Initially, every PIN starts with a length of 4 digits, i.e. 2345, 5456 and so on. However, I am trying to make it so that if all 4 digit pins are used, then it increases to 5 digits, then 6 etc. Essentially so you won't run out!

I'm using laravel and have created a trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Models\Quiz;

trait QuizPinTrait
{
    private $pin = null;
    private $min, $max;

    private function setup() 
    {
        $this->min = 1111;
        $this->max = 9999;
        $this->pin = mt_rand($this->min, $this->max);
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        $this->setup();
        if ($this->checkNotInUse()) {
            return $this->pin;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function checkNotInUse()
    {
        $inUse = Quiz::where('pin', $this->pin)->count();

        if (!$inUse || $inUse == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // stuck here...
        }
    }
}
```

I first thought about appending a 1 to the min value and 9 to the max, although, I'm unsure about how to make an efficient solution for this.

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an array of ints, `[1111,...,9999]` and diff against the array of in use PINs to get the available PINs.

```
$isUse = Quiz:all()->pluck('pin');
$min = 1111;
$max = 9999;
$allPins = range($min,$max);
$notInUse = array_diff($allPins, $inUse);


// laravel one liner
$notInUse = collect(Quiz:all()->pluck('pin'))->diff(range($min,$max));
```

Then when no more are available for the current range:

```
$min = $max+1;
$max *= 10;
```

Comment: A concept is there, although it might not exactly.. scale as written.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that requires less memory.

Pick a random number between 0 and 9999. This is your key. Then you can just do as follows:

```
function getPin() {

  static $lastPin = 0;
  $key = 4864;
  $lastPin++;
  return $lastPin ^ $key;

}

// Example: displaying lots of pins 
$i=0;
while($i++<10002) {
  echo getPin(), "\n";
}
```

The drawback of this is that it's not as random.